# Is there a way to connect to MS Access .accdb through edge.js

Tags: c#, node.js, ms-access, edge.js

I need the ability to connect to an .accdb MS Access 2007 database through nodejs.  I currently do this through the [win32ole](https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole) library.  This library seems to have lost support and hasn't been updated to work with node v.12.

I'm currently using edge.js to connect to SQL Server 2012.  I'm wondering if there is the possibility of connecting to the .accdb DB through this also.  It seems to utilize ADO.NET for its sql functions.  My understanding is MS Access needs either native ODBC or OLEDB.

If not through the sql function of edge.js, another possibility would be to write C# to use OLEDB to connect to MS ACCESS, all encapsulated within edge.js.  Are there any examples of this being done?

My last alternative is to find another seperate libary to connect to MS Access in Node.js.  They seem pretty rare.  [Node-Adodb](https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb) might work though..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the OleDb* classes to connect to MS Access. You could wrap them in a class and call that from edge.js. An example of that is https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge-sql, where Sql* classes are exposed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I chose an alternative library, [node-adodb](https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb), which works fine with Node.js v.12.

I believe connecting through C# libraries and exposing that to javascript through edge.js is a viable alternative also, but is also more unnecessarily complicated.